# Add html input boxes to a div on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add input boxes to a page onclick of a button, I have written the following jquery script. It adds one input box when clicked the first time but does not repeat adding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addInput(){
      $('#fileinput').html('<label>Filename:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file"  id="file" />');
   }
</script>
```

can some one please help me to modify the code so that it will add an input box each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#fileinput').html($('#fileinput').html()+'<label>Filename:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file"  id="file" />');
});
```

or use append as others suggested

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#fileinput').append('<label>Filename:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file"  id="file" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently replaces the existing HTML in your `#fileInput` element with the same HTML. What you probably want to use is the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
   function addInput(){
      $('#fileinput').append('<label>Filename:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file"  id="file" />');
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `append` instead of `html`: http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addInput(){
  $('#fileinput').append('<label>Filename:</label>
              <input type="file" name="file"  id="file" />');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not *adding* to the HTML each time, you're simply setting it to show the single `input`.